# Can't using DomXpath to crawl data although the element have values

Tags: php, html, xpath, web-crawler

I have a problem when crawling data [from this site.](https://www.bukalapak.com/p/elektronik/media-player-set-top-box/2kc5y0-jual-set-top-box-dvb-t2-venus-brio-receiver-tv-digital-full-hd-usb-in-hdmi?utm_source=homepage&utm_medium=popular_promo&from=popular-section-4)

Two fields include: `name` and `prices` of `Products`.

Bellow is Xpath of each element. Show:

`name`   : `//*[@id="mod-product-detail-1"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/h1`

`prices` : `//*[@id="mod-product-detail-1"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/span/span[2]`

I apply my code to get this. But I can't get anything.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

if ($doc->loadHTMLfile($url)) {

    libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

    $namepath = '//*[@id="mod-product-detail-1"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/h1';
    $pricepath = '//*[@id="mod-product-detail-1"]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/span/span[2]';

    //get name
    $elements = $xpath->query($namepath);
    if (!is_null($elements) && isset($elements[0]->nodeValue)) {
        $data['name'] = $elements[0]->nodeValue;
    } else {
        $data['name'] = '';
    }

    //get price
    $price = $xpath->query($pricepath);
    if (!is_null($price) && isset($price[0]->nodeValue)) {
        $data['price'] = filter_var($price[0]->nodeValue, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    } else {
        $data['price'] = '';
    }
}
```

I think my code correct, but it can't get any info on Products.

Can anyone help me explain I fail at any step in my code?

Comment: Cannot see `mod-product-detail-1` id in the view source page. But can find it in the console. which means these contents are loading after page loaded.

Comment: Seem correct. Have any method to get it? If it does not include in the page. I can't find Xpath.

Comment: They are loaded by Javascript, so you would need something that can execute the JS. A headless browser like PhantomJS might work. However here might be legal issues and you will be a lot better of using an API provided by the page.

Comment: Thanks, @ThW. I want to crawler news. Any site provider RSS link, any site must be crawler data.